# How to auto redirect errors from API in ASP.Net Razor Pages to error page?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm making Razor Pages app and I'm using `HttpClient` to make request from `PageModel` to some API. (`ApiClient` is basically class which derives from `HttpClient`

```
  public class IndexModel : MyPageModel {
    public IndexModel(ApiClient client) : base(client) { }

    public void OnGet() {
      var response = _client.PostAsync("account/login", new StringContent("")).Result;
      var status = response.StatusCode; // If status == BadRequest, redirect to Error.html
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set automatic redirect if I get **400 BadRequest** or other error from API?
Or do I need to check it every time, when I'm sending a request?

I know, that I can use `Redirect` or something, but I want to make it automatic.

@EDIT

Nevermind, my project was closed. Thanks for help anyways!

Comment: First of all you need to create a controller method with return a error page with `return Redirect("path");`

Answer (score 1):

For `HttpClient`, you could not redirect inside `HttpClient`. You could only redirect in `PageModel`.

For a workaround, you could try throw `Exception` in `ApiClient.PostAsync` and use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` to redirect to the error page.

1. Define `ApiClient`

   ```
   public class ApiClient : HttpClient
   {
   public Func<HttpResponseMessage, HttpResponseMessage> Action => (response) =>
   {
       if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
           throw new Exception(response.ToString());
       }
       return response;
   };
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
   {
       var result = await base.GetAsync(requestUri);
       return Action(result);
   }

   }
   ```
2. Register `ApiClient`

   ```
       services.AddScoped<ApiClient>();
   ```
3. Call from `PageModel`

   ```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
   private readonly ApiClient _apiClient;
   public IndexModel(ApiClient apiClient)
   {
       _apiClient = apiClient;
   }
   public async Task OnGet()
   {
       var result3 = await _apiClient.GetAsync("https://www.baidu.com/");
   }
   ```
4. Implement your required method from `HttpClient` like `PostAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle like this for all the response code except Ok (200)..

```
public void OnGet() {
      var response = _client.PostAsync("account/login", new StringContent("")).Result;
      var status = response.StatusCode;
      if(status != HttpStatusCode.OK){
          //redirect to error page
      }
    }
```

Comment: So... it's not auto as I asked. I have to write if check every time... I know I can make simple if. But thanks for effort

Comment: From auto what you meant to achieve?

Comment: Auto check for errors in request like `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` It's redirecting to error page automatically, when **Exception** occurs

Answer (score 0):

It's not compatible with Razor Pages, because frankly APIs aren't really compatible with Razor Pages. However, with an actual controller (and ASP.NET Core 2.1+), you can decorate it with the `[ApiController]` attribute. ASP.NET Core, then, will (among other things) automatically return a 400 with `ModelState` converted to JSON whenever `ModelState` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Hmm.. Can I override `HttpClient` and implement some **Observator** call (for example in `HttpClient.GetAsync()`) method, which will take care for redirecting or this all is just gibberish?

Comment: Maybe using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect`?